# Get list of all names in content provider

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I'm using "Calls.CONTENT_URI" content provider. I already retrived column names, but now i would like to get let's say, ALL names from column name "name" in this content provider.

I have code below:

```
uri = Calls.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {"name"};
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sort = null;


    resolver = getContentResolver();

    cursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sort);
    Log.i("TUTORIAL", "counts :"+cursor.getCount());    

    String s;
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    for(int x=0; x<cursor.getCount(); x++){

        s = cursor.getString(x);
        Log.i("TUTORIAL", ""+s);

        //cursor.moveToNext();


    }
```

But this retrives only one name. I would like to have list of all names saved in my phone like:

John
Peter
Mark
Suzy
.
.
X

But now i got just one name like:

Peter.
Hope i've been clear enough.

What's the problem? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would help you

```
        ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] projection = {"name"};
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sort = null;
    resolver = getContentResolver();
    cursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sort);
    Log.i("TUTORIAL", "counts :"+cursor.getCount());    
    String s;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            nameList.add(cursor.getString(0));
            //your code
            //s = cursor.getString(x);
            Log.i("TUTORIAL", ""+cursor.getString(0));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: and how do i get the actual name from table? I think i shouldn't use "cursor.getString(x); " ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one , it's working for me :

```
public void readContacts() {
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    // Get contact id (id)
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    // Get contact name (displayName)
                    String displayName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                }
            }
        }
        cur.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // The contacts from the contacts content provider is stored in this cursor
    mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id","name","photo","details"} );

    // Adapter to set data in the listview
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.lv_layout,
            null,
            new String[] { "name","photo","details"},
            new int[] { R.id.tv_name,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.tv_details}, 0);

    // Getting reference to listview
    ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);

    // Setting the adapter to listview
    lstContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load listview with contacts
    ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new ListViewContactsLoader();

    // Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with contacts
    listViewContactsLoader.execute();
}

/** An AsyncTask class to retrieve and load listview with contacts */
private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void...  params) {
        Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        // Querying the table ContactsContract.Contacts to retrieve all the contacts
        Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");

        if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                long contactId = contactsCursor.getLong(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));

                Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

                // Querying the table ContactsContract.Data to retrieve individual items like
                // home phone, mobile phone, work email etc corresponding to each contact
                Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, null,
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId,
                        null, null);

                String displayName="";
                String nickName="";
                String homePhone="";
                String mobilePhone="";
                String workPhone="";
                //String photoPath="" + R.drawable.blank;
                byte[] photoByte=null;
                String homeEmail="";
                String workEmail="";
                String companyName="";
                String title="";

                if(dataCursor.moveToFirst()){
                    // Getting Display Name
                    displayName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME ));
                    do{

                        // Getting NickName
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
                            nickName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));

                        // Getting Phone numbers
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                                    homePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                                    mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK :
                                    workPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        // Getting EMails
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE ) ) {
                            switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME :
                                    homeEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK :
                                    workEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        // Getting Organization details
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            companyName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                            title = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data4"));
                        }

                        // Getting Photo
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            photoByte = dataCursor.getBlob(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data15"));

                            if(photoByte != null) {
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoByte, 0, photoByte.length);

                                // Getting Caching directory
                                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                                // Temporary file to store the contact image
                                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+contactId+".png");

                                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                                try {
                                    FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                                    // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

                                    // Flush the FileOutputStream
                                    fOutStream.flush();

                                    //Close the FileOutputStream
                                    fOutStream.close();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                               // photoPath = tmpFile.getPath();
                            }
                        }
                    }while(dataCursor.moveToNext());
                    String details = "";

                    // Concatenating various information to single string
                    if(homePhone != null && !homePhone.equals("") )
                        details = "HomePhone : " + homePhone + "\n";
                    if(mobilePhone != null && !mobilePhone.equals("") )
                        details += "MobilePhone : " + mobilePhone + "\n";
                    if(workPhone != null && !workPhone.equals("") )
                        details += "WorkPhone : " + workPhone + "\n";
                    if(nickName != null && !nickName.equals("") )
                        details += "NickName : " + nickName + "\n";
                    if(homeEmail != null && !homeEmail.equals("") )
                        details += "HomeEmail : " + homeEmail + "\n";
                    if(workEmail != null && !workEmail.equals("") )
                        details += "WorkEmail : " + workEmail + "\n";
                    if(companyName != null && !companyName.equals("") )
                        details += "CompanyName : " + companyName + "\n";
                    if(title != null && !title.equals("") )
                        details += "Title : " + title + "\n";

                    // Adding id, display name, path to photo and other details to cursor
                    mMatrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{ Long.toString(contactId),displayName,null,details});
                }
            }while(contactsCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return mMatrixCursor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        // Setting the cursor containing contacts to listview
        mAdapter.swapCursor(result);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}